# Common distribution of two random variables

Tags: probability

$A$ and $B$ are random variables, which can have the values $0$ and $1.$

We know: $P(A = 1, B = 1) = \frac{1}{4}$, $P(A = 0) = \frac{2}{3}$, $P(B = 0\mid A = 0) = \frac{3}{4}$

I need to create a table with the Probabilities $P(A = x, B = y) := P({A = x} \cap {B = y})$

So this would be the starting point:

[image]

Now I have different solutions of which I'm not quite sure what are correct.

This is the first one which uses the law of total probability:[image]

And this is the second one:[image]

In both cases, the rest can be filled out easily.

Which one is correct and why is the other way wrong?

Comment: The second solution is correct, except you wrote $\frac34\cdot\frac24=\frac12$.  The first equation of of the first solution is wrong: $P(B=0)=P(B=0 \& A=0)+P(B=0 \& A=1)$, not what you had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the error:
$$
\require{cancel}
\xcancel{ \Pr(B=0) = \Pr(B=0\mid A=0)\Pr(A) \phantom{\int\cdots}}
$$
Here is how to do that correctly:
\begin{align}
& \Pr(B=0) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr(B=0\mid A=0)\Pr(A=0) \\[4pt]
& {} + \Pr(B=0\mid A=1)\Pr(A=1).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

The probability A being zero = $\frac{2}{3}$

The probability of A being 1 is =$\frac{1}{3}$

We know $\frac{P(A[0]\cap B[0])}{P(A[0])}= \frac{3}{4}$ , therefore $P(A[0]\cap B[0]) = \frac{1}{2}$

$P(A[0])\ =\ P(A[0]\cap B[0]) + P(A[0]\cap B[1])$ , therefore $P(A[0]\cap B[1])= \frac{1}{6}$

Same way $P(A[1]\cap B[0]) = \frac{1}{12}$

(The probabilities are not independent).